# ListView wrap grid with dynamic height

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

In my Windows Store app I have ListView that contains elements of various sizes in height. How can I make ListView had two or more columns with elements not fixed height?

Example from Android app:
[image]

This vertical scrolling list, but comes in two columns where height of each cell is not fixed.
I try use VariableSizedWrapGrid, but it throw exception `The Panel you are using for the Control is not allowed as an ItemsPanel for the Control.`

My current code display multiple columns, but elements have fixed height.

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" ItemHeight="300" ItemWidth="500"/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

[This](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/gridview-with-variable-b2346047) example suggest use DataTemplateSelector. This means that I must know all the options of possible heights of elements, but real content is not known in advance.

Comment: Do you need to handle a lot of data? I mean, do you need data virtualization for this list?

Comment: @JustinXL Yes, it's endless list with text and pictures.